# AFind the number of rational numbers lying in the interval $(2002,2003)$ all whose digits after decimal point are non zero and in decreasing order.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

According to me, the answer should be $$\sum _{i=0}^9 P^9_i$$

Since the order clearly matters here.

But the answer is $$2^9-1$$

Which implies the use of combinatorics. How can combinatorics be used if the question specifically mentions that the order matters in this case?

Comment: Why would you sum?  There are $2^9$ subsets of $\{1,\cdots, 9\}$  any of these can be arranged in decreasing order in exactly one way so they all work, save for $\emptyset$.

Comment: @lulu that makes sense. Thanks!